# How to access parent page UserControl is in

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `UserControl` that is placed into a Page. How do I access the `Page` the `UserControl` is in?

My user case, I want the constructor or method of my `UserControl` to add to the hierarchy of the Page it's located on. When the button of the `UserControl` is clicked, it will place or make visible a `Canvas` on top of it's `Parent` `Page`

Answer (score 1):

In a simple case of `UserControl` added to a `Page`, the First `Parent` of the `UserControl` when it is placed in a page is the `FrameworkElement` and the `Parent` of the `FrameworkElement` will be the page.

For Example: If `MyUserControl` is my `UserControl` and `MainPage` is the page that I am adding the `UserControl` to, Then you can get the `MainPage` from inside the `UserControl` where `Button` is clicked on is like below.

```
var page = ((FrameworkElement)myControl.Parent).Parent;
```

and then you can check for page type and process your commands accordingly.

**Here is a full snippet**

```
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var page = ((FrameworkElement)myControl.Parent).Parent;
    if (page.GetType() == typeof(MainPage))
    {
        (page as MainPage).ShowData();
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: In my case it was to access the parent Window: `var window = ((FrameworkElement)Parent).Parent as Window;`

Answer (score -2):

UserControl has the Page in it's definition, so you should be able to access it from `this.Page`.

Comment: "Page" is not a property of UserControl